# Why does Redis offer range partitioning?

Tags: redis, partitioning

i've read this article(https://redis.io/topics/partitioning#why-partitioning-is-useful) about redis partitioning

i could find that redis offers two partitioning method options, range partitioning and hash partitioning.

for me, range partitioning seems no good compare to hash partitioning in every aspect.

I think range partitioning has some good points but I don't know what they are.

please give me some ideas about it.

Comment: @pjs I'm thinking about partition my data by first letter of an English words. so the distribution of English words is matter. but rethinking about my question, distribution tag seems not necessary. i will fix this.

Comment: Which sentence/paragraph made you think that Redis *offers* range partitioning?

Comment: @sazzad you can find it partition basic part 2nd paragraph. One of the simplest ways to perform partitioning is with range partitioning...

Comment: added an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redis **does not offer** range partitioning.

Redis offers hash partitioning but only in cluster mode.

The article you mentioned just gives basic idea about how users can use different partitioning scheme (not only range partitioning but others as well) to distribute their data.

Comment: I was unsure about that but now it is clear. thanks